# How do i know if version changes for gmail-api?

Tags: google-api, version, gmail-api

I just want to know if there are any version changes published for gmail-api then how do i come to know and if there any should i have to change the api also in my code or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/release-notes)  page.

[image]

This page contains the public changes that have been made to the api.  Everything else is internal and we are not informed about it.

Comment: thank you @DalmTo very much for your prompt reply. Another thing i want to know if there are any API kind of link from which we can get the information about version or manually have to always check if new version is available?

Comment: version number for the API only change for major version.  You could check the directory services api it returns a list of all Apis if a new major version comes it will be there

Comment: please remember to accept the anwser if it helps you